# How to retrieve edited data from extjs property grid?

Tags: php, ajax, grid, extjs4.2

**I have this simple code:**

```
var store = {
    "(name)": "My Object",
    "Created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
    "Available": false,
    "Version": 0.01,
    "Description": "A test object"
}


Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: store,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        ui: 'footer',
        items: ['->', {
            //iconCls: 'icon-save',
            text: 'Sync',
            scope: this,
            // handler: this.onSync
        }]
    }]
});
```

**The panel looks like this:**

[image]

My app uses similar grid, the only difference is that the **`store`** variable is created dynamically (*but has similar structure*) and I also have a **`sync`** button that should save any changes to the grid's `value` field.

As of now, value field can be edited but not saved anywhere of course. I have been trying to add an event on **`sync`** button click, that would get all the rows from `value` and update the database.

**Can anyone tell me step-by-step what to add in `property.Grid`'s code, so that when I click `sync`
it would send all the `values` via AJAX to my `php file`, that would do the sync with database?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{
    text: 'Sync',
    handler: function() {
       // get values
       var gridvalues = this.up( 'propertygrid' ).getSource();
       // send AJAX request
       Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: 'somephpurl...',
           params: gridvalues
       });
    }
}
```

The docs, BTW, for these are as follows:

Get property grid values: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-getSource

Create AJAX request: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request

Comment: I get an error:  `this.up is not a function`. What is 'propertygrid'?

Comment: What's your code look like? This works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/wMcQk/46/

Comment: "propertygrid" is the xtype of the Ext.grid.property.Grid: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid